# How do Opioids Stimulate a Histamine Release?

Tags: pharmacology, opioid, histamine

Histamine is a neurotransmitter that also has peripheral functions such as the regulation of gastric acid secretions, allergic responses, etc. I know that opioids stimulate a release of histamine but I want to know how?

What exactly I would like answered is:

- Which of the opioid receptors are involved in the histamine release that opioids stimulate and to what extent are they?
- How does the activation of the opioid receptors in question lead to a release of histamine?
- Are there any ways of suppressing the histamine release stimulated by opioids without compromising the analgesia they elicit?

I would like an answer, not just links. However I would like you to cite journal articles, although a formal reference list is not required so long as I can easily find the link to the abstract/full article.

Comment: This might get you started: consider the references in http://www.acnp.org/g4/GN401000037/CH037.html, especially in the section "modulation of histamine synthesis and release in vivo".  This is not my area of expertise, so I will leave it to someone else to explain things.